# Extending a list in Elvish shell (modifying $PATH)

Tags: list, shell, elvish

By default Elvish (macOS, Homebrew) has a basic PATH definition:

```
~> echo $paths
[/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin]
```

I'd like to add `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` items to it, but without writing literals from scratch like

```
set paths = [/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]
```

Basic pattern for more common shells is, of course

```bash
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Lists in Elvish are immutable, so I'd like to do something like

```
set paths = paths + [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]
```

But I haven't find anything in docs, and my attempts fail:

```
~> set paths = paths + [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]
Exception: arity mismatch: assignment right-hand-side must be 1 value, but is 3 values
[tty 2]:1:1: set paths = paths + [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]

~> set paths = [$paths /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]
Exception: path must be string
[tty 3]:1:5: set paths = [$paths /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either modify the path directly with `set E:PATH = "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$E:PATH`, or use `conj` like this `set paths = (conj $paths /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin)`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Pavlo and their notion of [`conj`](https://elv.sh/ref/builtin.html#conj), I've found yet another way of doing it, so I'll list it here for completeness:

```
set paths = [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin $@paths]
```

This upside here is an ability to *pre*pend values to a list (`conj` does appending only), which is obviously important in the general case, but also in managing `$PATH` as well.